# Running Proxy servlet on Openshift

Tags: java, openshift

This app http://bit.ly/1vNUIsU originally worked with Openshift, after deleting the app, then re-creating, its not working anymore, its very odd. The same code worked before. Not sure what happened.

In any case, I've tried everything, `rhc app-tidy` and `rhc tail` but the app just keeps loading

```
Error 503 when accessed.
```

I am not sure if the issue is with Restlet as it worked before. What could be the issues of Restlet with Openshift just in case?

**Code:**

```
public class FirstStepsApplication extends Application {
    private static final String ROOT_URI = "/";
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        Redirector proxy = new Redirector(getContext(), Constants.root,
                Redirector.MODE_SERVER_OUTBOUND){
            @Override
            public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
                String path = request.getResourceRef().getHostIdentifier() +
                        request.getResourceRef().getPath();
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(path);
                    String host = url.getHost();
                    String pathParts = url.getPath();
                    if(pathParts.isEmpty() || pathParts.equals(ROOT_URI)){
                        pathParts = "/index.html";
                    }
                    String targetPattern = Constants.root + host + pathParts;
                    System.out.println("Target URL = " + targetPattern);
                    this.setTargetTemplate(targetPattern);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                super.handle(request, response);
            }
        };
        getConnectorService().getClientProtocols().add(Protocol.HTTP);
        router.attachDefault(proxy);
        return router;
    }
}
```

This code worked with Opensift/JBoss before. Not it wont.

Comment: You should try posting an issue on that github project and see if the author can help you resolve the issue.  Or at least point them to this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: I am the author of this github project actually :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with Tomcat 7 Cartridge instead of JBoss/Capedwarf