# Reponse truncated to 8K (incomplete response)

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy, openshift, restlet

I have two (2) possible solution for my problem that my proxy server is returning incomplete or truncated response.

1. Openshift issue
2. Application or Restlet issue

My app is deployed with a Tomcat 7 cartrige with Openshift, so far it works fine the only things is that response gets truncated.

E.g.

```
<div>..<d
```

The missing/incomplete div tag and those kind of issues due to truncating. Is this kind of issue needs to be solved from RedHat's Openshift or fixing with Resteasy code is possible?

After searching a bit, it seems this is a common issue, response being truncated to 8k:

- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61656
- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44494

Comment: Proxy servers are not allowed on OpenShift.  Your application will probably get taken down due to ToS.

Comment: Not allowed in Openshift?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OpenShift does not allow the running of Proxy Servers.

Comment: @developercorey I think you are mistaken, it seems Openshift does not regard what app you put in, see: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/setup-a-proxy-server-with-encryption

Comment: also its not a "full" proxy server its more of a mirror that i am doing so why off-topic?

Comment: Does it copy the code from google app engine onto your OpenShift gear and run it there?  Can you further explain how your proxy works then?

Comment: I don't quite understand... I am just running Restlet Redirector

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649443/running-proxy-servlet-on-openshift

Comment: Did you read the last comment on the https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/setup-a-proxy-server-with-encryption forum post?

Comment: I dont think my app is anywhere near to being a real proxy server, its just a Servlet